# Laravel - Unable to read the config file for my custom package (neither the package's copy nor the published one)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have a custom package I am modifying that we use at our company (someone else wrote it) and I am implementing a new view composer. To make it work I am building a composer provider that loads information from a config file. This will allow us to use this package in multiple projects.

In this provider I am unable to get information from either config file. The one in the package itself, nor the one I published to my project.

As you will see below I have tried several ways to get to the configuration information. When I print the output to the screen I don't see any of the contents of the config file. I also have both providers listed in the projects app.php file under providers. So I can put debug code into either and see it on the screen.

So how, exactly, do I get it to pickup the config information?

**I have tried accessing the config in the following ways:**

```
$pages = \Config::get('laravel::pages'); //The specific array
$items = \Config::getItems(); //All config info
$config = $this->app['config']; //The more direct approach
```

At this point you probably need to some more code from me and more about the structure.

**Here is the folder structure:**

```
/vendor
    /bas
        /laravel
            /src
                /BAS
                    /Laravel
                        /Provider
                            /ViewComposerProvider.php
                            /LaravelServiceProvider.php
                /config
                    /config.php
```

**Contents of the ViewComposerProvider.php:**

```
<?php
namespace BAS\Laravel\Provider;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewComposerProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function register()
    {
        /**
         * This has to be declared as a singleton due to the wildcard view
         * selector in the related boot function.
         *
         * If it were not a singleton then we would hit ldb for company
         * data once for every view and subview that is built.
         */
        \App::singleton(
            'BAS\Laravel\Composers\ICompanyComposer',
            'BAS\Laravel\Composers\CompanyComposer'
        );

        \App::singleton(
            'BAS\Laravel\Composers\IJavascriptLoggerComposer',
            'BAS\Laravel\Composers\JavascriptLoggerComposer'
        );
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        /**
         * Default for the array looks like this:
         *
         * array(
         *   'BAS\Laravel\Composers\ICompanyComposer' => array('company::pages.*'),
         *   'BAS\Laravel\Composers\IJavascriptLoggerComposer' => array('company::base')
         * );
         */
        \View::composers( $this->getComposers() );
    }

    public function getComposers()
    {
        $app = $this->app;
        /**
         * This package is called Laravel, so this could get confusing.
         *
         * @var Array $pages
         */
        $pages = \Config::get('laravel::pages');
        $composerList = array();
        /*echo "Pages:<pre>" . print_r($pages, true) . "</pre>";

        $items = \Config::getItems();
        echo "Items:<pre>" . print_r($items, true) . "</pre>";

        $config = $app['config'];
        echo "Config:<pre>" . print_r($config, true) . "</pre>";
        die();*/

        foreach ($pages as $pageType => $pageList) {
            $composer = $this->getComposerByPageType($pageType);
            $composerList[$composer] = $pageList;
        }

        return $composerList;
    }

    public function getComposerByPageType($type)
    {
        $composer = '';

        switch ( strtolower($type) ) {
            case 'company':
                $composer = 'BAS\Laravel\Composers\ICompanyComposer';
                break;

            case 'javascript':
                $composer = 'BAS\Laravel\Composers\IJavascriptLoggerComposer';
                break;
        }

        return $composer;
    }
}
```

**Here is the content of the LaravelServiceProvider.php:**

```
<?php
namespace BAS\Laravel\Provider;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class LaravelServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = false;

    public function boot()
    {
        //$this->package('bas/laravel');
    }

    public function register()
    {
        $this->package('bas/laravel');
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

**And finally the contents of the config file:**

```
<?php
return array(
    'pages' => array(
        'company' => array('company::pages.*', 'card-process'),
        'javascript' => array('company::base')
    ),
);
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://coderwall.com/p/svocrg/configurations-and-namespaces-in-package-development-for-laravel

Comment: Unfortunately it did not. That said, next time please submit it as an answer so that there is a possibility of upvoting it and giving you points.